The public directory not found
I have a problem with the public directory I can't find the file in my desktop but when I run the hosting setup in the terminal its said that is already existing
I have this error
Error: Directory 'public' for Hosting does not exist.
? File public/404.html already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of public/404.html
? File public/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No

the firebase.json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

I want to publish my website using Firebase
